# How to select fields from three different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is driving me crazy, i've spent hours in this and i just don't know what to do:

i have 3 tables:

- users
- companies
- company_permissions

in users i have coduser and username
in companies codcompany and company_name
and in company_permissions i have idcompany_permissions, codcompany, coduser

what i want to do is basically, with one query, get the name of the company to which the given username has permissions to access.

i had this query:

```
select users.coduser, users.username, companies.company_name
from users
inner join company_permissions on users.coduser = company_permissions.coduser
inner join companies on companies.codcompany = company_permissions.codcompany
where users.username = 'test'
```

But it doesn't return anything :C (it did at one point but now it doesn't do it)

Comment: The reasonable conclusion is that no data exists with `users.user = 'test'` or that there are no matches in the `company_permissions` table.  You might consider putting an example on SQL Fiddle that illustrates the problem with sample data.

Comment: It is there though, i created the table and the entry manualy and it shows up with a select where username = 'test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no error with your query

check the database if the user 'test' exists

if it's exist because you using inner join it must be records in all three tables

check them again

Comment: Ooh thank you, the problem was with one of the id's being different in codcompany from the two tables, thanks! :D i thought i messed up my query :c

Answer (score 0):

I think for this case, you should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.
Anyway, WHERE users.user = 'test', I guest the field must be username.

Comment: why LEFT JOIN? o:
and sorry about the users.users, that was a typo as i had to retype everything since the tables and fields were in spanish x_x

Answer (score 0):

Test your statement step by step

1.)

```
select users.* from users 
--inner join company_permissions on users.coduser = company_permissions.coduser
--inner join companies on companies.codcompany = company_permissions.codcompany
where users.username = 'test'
```

is there a result... user-data is exist

2.)

```
select users.*
from users
inner join company_permissions on users.coduser = company_permissions.coduser
--inner join companies on companies.codcompany = company_permissions.codcompany
where users.username = 'test'
```

is there a result... the join between company_permissions and users is ok (data exist)

3.)

```
select users.*
from users
--inner join company_permissions on users.coduser = company_permissions.coduser
inner join companies on companies.codcompany = company_permissions.codcompany
where users.username = 'test'
```

is there a result the join between companies and company_permissions is ok..